# Redis installation error on CentOS 5.8

Tags: compilation, redis, centos5

I was trying to compile Redis 2.6.4 on CentOS 5.8 but I was getting the following error after running `make`

> zmalloc.o: In function `zmalloc_used_memory':
>   /root/redis-2.6.4/src/zmalloc.c:223: undefined reference to`
>   __sync_add_and_fetch_4' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]:
>   *** [redis-server] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/redis-2.6.4/src' make: *** [all] Error 2

I also tried `CFLAGS= -march=i686` in the `src/Makefile` but did not work. Actually, I don't know where to put it. I put at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it done. I run the following command which seems worked correctly (though later I need to install tcl8.5).

```
make 32bit
```

Answer (score 2):

1 add `CFLAGS= -march=i686` to src/Makefile top

2 change src/.make_settings `OPT=-O2` into `OPT=-O2 -march=i686`

3 then `make 32bit`

4 `make test`

That works for me.

Ps. maybe you would got `tcl` problem

1 `rpm -qa | grep tcl` to see whether tcl version is blow 8.5

2 if so `yum remove tcl`

3 go to http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/tcl.html to got a newest one and install

4 go to redis directory `make test`

Answer (score 0):

As @HungryCoder said, simple "make 32bit" command would work.

But sometimes,  if your have already run into error, you'd better remove files named .make*  before running it.

```
make distclean
make
```

If it didn't help, try to figure out your CPU arch manually by run the following:

```
export CFLAGS=`uname -m`
make distclean
make
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues compiling it and I solved by first installing the following dependencies:

```
sudo yum -y install libstdc++*
sudo yum -y install libstdc++*.i686
```

Then I could run the proper make without any problem

```
make 32bit
```

I hope this helps someone.